# Элемент не меняет видимость при удалении класса

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function onFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

 //Делаю анимацию загрузки видимой
    var loader = document.querySelector('#processLoadingWrapper');
    loader.classList.remove('d-none');

 //В это время типа происходят всякие процессы
    sleep(2000);
    
    
 //Скрываю анимацию загрузки
    loader.classList.add('d-none');
}

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);
```

```css
.d-none{
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

<div class="d-none" id="processLoadingWrapper">
  Тут анимация загрузки
</div>
```

Мне нужно при отправке формы показать блок с анимацией загрузки. По умолчанию он скрыт. А после того как загрузка завершится, снова скрыть этот блок.

Смотрю у себя в коде - при нажатии на submit класс d-none пропадает, но блок не становится видимым. Если убрать этот класс из кода руками, то все ок. В чем тут дело?

UPD. Добавлю пример настоящего кода

```js
function onFilterFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector('#processLoadingWrapper').classList.remove('d-none');

    var formData = new FormData(evt.target);
    var fields = []
    for(var field of formData.entries()) {
        if(field[1] != '---' && field[1].length > 0){
           fields.push(field);
        }
    }


    var queryString = new URLSearchParams(fields).toString();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/ajax-tires/?' + queryString, false);
    xhr.send(formData);
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      console.log( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText );
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#main-content-wrapper').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      addProductToggleHandler();
    }

    document.querySelector('#processLoadingWrapper').classList.add('d-none');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    tireFilterForm.addEventListener('submit', onFilterFormSubmit);
});
```

Comment: *К слову, "замораживать" скрипт бесконечным циклом - плохая идея) Вместо этого можно использовать `setTimeout(function(){ /* всё что нужно выполнить через 2 сек */ },2000);`

Comment: Ну мне нужна была какая-то пауза для примера, я просто ее нагуглил. По-настоящему в коде ничего этого нет. Между удалением и добавлением d-none происходит ajax-запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Если не забивать основной поток пустым циклом который будет съедать ресурсы, то никакой проблемы с отображением элемента не будет.

```js
function onFormSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var loader = document.querySelector('#processLoadingWrapper');
    
    loader.classList.remove('d-none');
    setTimeout(function(){
           loader.classList.add('d-none');
       }, 2000);        
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onFormSubmit);
```

```css
.d-none{
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <button type="">Отправить</button>
</form>

<div class="d-none" id="processLoadingWrapper">
  Тут анимация загрузки
</div>
```

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос пример реального кода этого куска. А с ним что не так? :( Класс четко пропадает и появляется, но визуально ничего не происходит.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME в приведенном примере как раз-таки синхронный вызов.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров в разных браузерах поведение одинаковое?

Comment: Нет, в хроме не работает, а в FireFox все нормально. Я уже всю голову сломал

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров чего ломать то, код сам по себе нормальный. класс снимается, вы сами это видите. мб хром тупит слегка и не успевает перерисовать содержимое страницы, а потом  ваш синхронный запрос вовсе фризит все что есть. Если вы используете аякс, то зачем это делаете синхронно? пишите асинхронный код.

Comment: Спасибо большое, это помогло.